# Creating a Custom UIButton with a Normal/Highlighted image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uikit

I'm trying to make a button with that switches images when it's highlighted or not. However the below code doesn't switch the images or even calls the selected method..

```
UIButton *shootButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[shootButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Button_Normal"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[shootButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Button_Highlighted"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
shootButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80);
[shootButton addTarget:self action:@selector(shoot) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self addSubview:shootButton];
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm looking at similar answers and it tells me I'm doing it right..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you are absolutely sure that image names are correct and in your project.

If you are doing `[self addSubview]` you must be adding the button a subclass of `UIView`.  Not sure what method you are adding the button, but it probably isn't the right one.  Instead, try adding the button in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`in the `UIViewController` containing the `UIView`

Comment: The problem was I was loading the button in UIView's initWithFrame method. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add these to detect the states of the button:

```
[self.botonSeguir addTarget:self action:@selector(setBgColorForButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self.botonSeguir addTarget:self action:@selector(clearBgColorForButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragExit];
[self.botonSeguir addTarget:self action:@selector(setBgColorForButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragEnter];
```

The first one detects when pressing the button (not yet released the finger)

The second one detects when you are still touching the screen button moved your finger away the button

And the third triggers if, after the second one you come back to the button.

And then create the methods setBgColorForButton, clearBgColorForButton and setBgColorForButton.

Comment: There are more events, obviously, these were the ones I had already coded. Try `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` and  `UIControlEventTouchDown`